# python opencv median a movie

Tags: python, opencv, median, movie

Trying to perform a median calculation on a part of a video. I've figured out parts of ti but do not know if this is the most efficient way

```
import cv2

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(videofile.h264)

for i in range(0,500):
    (grabbed,frame) = camera.read(i)
    if not grabbed:
        break
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    medstack.append(gray)

medst = np.median(medstack,axis=0)
```

The code will open the first 500 frames and store them in a python list. Following is then a median calculation across axis 0 (supposedly across the stack). The problem is that this ends with the file being converted into a float64 which messes with later calculations

```
while (camera.isOpened()):
    (grabbed,frame) = camera.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    subframe = gray-medst
    rgbframe = cv2.cvtColor(subframe,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    out.write(rgbframe)
```

I thought about converting the float64 into a uint8 to fix the issue but I also tried to convert the float64 into a BGR array, which the code is trying but fails to do.

Comment: why not doing [median blur](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga564869aa33e58769b4469101aac458f9) from opencv directly to the image before appending it? (it supports BGR images, however the channels are treated separately)

Comment: I kind of need to maintain the resolution of the image as I will be doing a background subtraction in the second step. The code will be used on many different video files, each with tiny differences. The end goal is tracking so I thought it best to calculate median frames for each video and perform the subtraction.

Comment: Ohhh, I got you now, so you want to get the median of each pixel over all the images and not for a neighborhood in the same image. Well the float64 is expected in numpy (see the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.median.html).

Comment: Why didn't medst = np.uint8(np.median(medstack,axis=0)) solve the issue?

Comment: That did fix my problem with the float64. thanks

Comment: Lastly, everything appears to be working except for the very last `out.write()` function. for some reason it save a blank video even though everything looks correct in regards to format.

Answer (score 0):

So your first part is correct.

The problem is that you get a `float64` matrix. You can use the [`astype`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) from numpy to cast it to the other one needed. But you may loose information :(

Try rounding the number first or selecting `ceil` or `floor` as you need to get what you expect.

Also, remember that if you do that subtraction you may get negative numbers.... which you should also manage it. I mean this line:

```
subframe = gray-medst
```

And another comment more:

```
rgbframe = cv2.cvtColor(subframe,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
```

This gives you the same grayscale image, but with 3 channels (all with the same number) not sure if that is what you wanted.

Comment: I'm actually counting on the negative values during the subtraction. I'm trying to track black objects in a video and they usually appear as negative blobs in the processed picture. 

For why I need 3 channels. I need to save a video of the freely moving blobs without the background. I figured after grayscale and subtraction, I could convert it back into BGR and save. Doesn't appear to be working though

Comment: @Hojo.Timberwolf BGR to Grayscale is a lossy conversion, you loose information that cannot be recoered. If you are trying to find a blob of an specific color, try to use inrange and create a binary image out of it. Something like [this](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html)

Comment: I shall look into it. I'm actually using an IR camera and filter to record signal so theoretically all the channels should be the same. But I did notice small differences between the 3 channels.

Comment: @Hojo.Timberwolf I think IR cameras usually gives a greyscale image or a 16 bit one channel images. if you have 3 channels, maybe it is another info from the camera?

Comment: I'm using the raspberry pi noIR V2 camera with an 850nm filter. To record using the pi, we have chose to use the pi module picamera.start_recording() as this was the only way to achieve 30fps at a resolution of 1290x720.