# Faster way to create a temporal median filter for a video

Tags: python, image, video, filter, median

I am trying to create a median filter for a video. The goal is to create an image for every 5 frames whose pixel values correspond to the median value of the pixel for the 5 frames.

I can do so using several for cycles but I wanted a faster/simpler way to accomplish the same result. Any help?

UPDATE:

I tried to use the np.median function by defining the axis I want the median to be applied. When I tested it out with smaller arrays it worked just fine but when I transitioned to the images it did not work.

```
w = 5  # window
n = int(len(data)/w)  # new number of frames
fdata = np.zeros([n, len(data[0]), len(data[0][0])])

for i in range(0, n):
   it_data = data[ i*5 : 5*i+5 ]
   fdata[i] = np.median(it_data, axis=0)
```

The error I receive is on the last line:

`>>> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: I'll check if with numpy you can do something similar, for the moment I found it in MatLab look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693069/how-to-calculate-median-of-frames-efficient-in-matlab) and [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49058885/median-of-each-pixel-of-a-set-of-images), but not in Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have :), `a`, `b` and `c` are frames (let's say grayscale), you must stack them as if they were the RGB components (try the same with 5, it will work) and then apply the median to the outer axis (see [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62926893/finding-median-value-of-multiple-numpy-arrays) and [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443295/combine-3-separate-numpy-arrays-to-an-rgb-image-in-python/10463090)).

```py
import numpy as np
import random

a = np.array(
    [[ random.randint(0,10) for i in range(3) ],
     [ random.randint(0,10) for i in range(3) ]])

b = np.array(
    [[ random.randint(0,10) for i in range(3) ],
     [ random.randint(0,10) for i in range(3) ]])

c = np.array(
    [[ random.randint(0,10) for i in range(3) ],
     [ random.randint(0,10) for i in range(3) ]])

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
print('\n')

# batch = a[..., np.newaxis]
batch = np.stack((a,b,c))

print(batch.shape)
print(batch)

print('\n')

batch = np.median(batch, axis=0)

print(batch.shape)
print(batch)

print('\n...Test...')

print(
    np.median(
        (a[0,0],b[0,0],c[0,0])
    )
)
```

#### Check also

- [numpy.median](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.median.html)
- [numpy.newaxis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17394882/how-can-i-add-new-dimensions-to-a-numpy-array) ---> this one I don't really know how to add more arrays in the new dimension
- also you can try [this `cv2` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45810427/python-opencv-median-a-movie), I have no video to test it at the moment

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this and I'll give you feedback!

Comment: You're welcome, try also the cv2 solution but I think that inside of the builtin method it will happen something like the solution I gave.

Comment: I tried to apply the numpy.median but, despite working for small examples, it didn't work for my specific dataset. Check the updated post.

Comment: Did you tryed the cv2 solution? I will try this solution with a video and will let you know

Comment: I manage to make it work with the np.median. My problem was the data format. I had a list of np.arrays instead of a 3d-np.array. Thank you for all the help!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that , I think you can also do it for RGB frames (maybe applying the media for each channel)